# After i installed pywin32 package i could not import it

Tags: python, package

I installed the `pywin32` package but when i try to import win32api or win32com package  it display the below error :

```
import win32api
```

> ImportError: DLL load failed: the specified procedure could not be
> found

if I search for installed packages in the env using `pip list` it display the `pywin32` package
I inspect the downloaded package in the below path :

```
env/Lib/site-packages/pywin32-227.dist-info/top_level.txt
```

I found that the 2 packages that i try to import it exist it the above file like so

- `win23api`
- `win32com`

Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

I am installing the package on a offline pc it is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving these 2 files from the environment

- pythoncom37.dll
- pywintypes37.dll

into `C:\Windows\System32`

I don't know why it works but in my situation it solve me the problem